# installed new CPU, monitor gets no signal

Tags: display, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I installed a new CPU in my PC, but when I turn on the machine the fans start, but the monitor gets no signal.
there are no BEEPs, and the computer does not restart automatically (i read that for some people it does)

mother board: IPISB-CH2

GPU: ASUS 210

power supply: 300W (stock HP)

old CPU: Pentium G620

new CPU: i5 3470

i tried so far:
- a different monitor + different cable
- unplugging the AC and holding the on button for > 1 minute
- removing the CMOS battery for 15 sec
- putting jumper configuration to CMOS + PWD reset for 15 sec
- checking if I haven't by accident unplugged something from the motherboard
- removing the GPU and using the MOBO sockets

the only thing I can think of is the PSU is not delivering enough power, however for such a weak hardware setup it should suffice

any suggestions?
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HP's [documentation](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02854392) for your motherboard indicates that your new CPU is not supported by your motherboard

> Processor upgrade information

```
TDP: 95W
Socket type: LGA 1155
Motherboard supports the following processor upgrades:
    Intel Core i7-2xxx (Sandy Bridge) quad core
    Intel Core i5-2xxx (Sandy Bridge) quad core
    Intel Core i3-2xxx (Sandy Bridge) dual core
    Intel Core i3-2xxx/T (Sandy Bridge) dual core
    Intel Pentium G8xx (Sandy Bridge) dual core
    Intel Pentium G6xxx (Sandy Bridge) dual core
```

It appears only i5-2xxx CPUs are supported and your new one is an i5-3xxx processor, which is not in the list

Comment: I found different information here:
http://www.pc-specs.com/cpu/Intel/Core_i5_3rd_Gen/Core_i5-3470_3.2GHz/931/Compatible_Motherboards

but I guess the official site should be more reliable

Comment: @balint I think that site is decent, but it looks like they're just checking that the chipset and socket match between motherboard and CPU, which is necessary, but not sufficient to determine if they're compatible